# Setting Email for Bootstrap 3 Contact Form Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to implement this responsive Bootstrap form modal.

http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/3Sbpv22LUp

My questions are:

- Where do I set the email address that the contact form will send to and
- If I include the contact form as an external js file, how would I go about that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files you provided are only to validate the form. thus, if you need to send an email, must use another scripting lenguage like php running on the server side. in that file write all the necesary code in order to send the email. For example I use this piece of code.

```
<?php
///subscribe form
    $recipient = "test@test.com"; ///  Your Email address
    if (isset($_POST['email'])){
        //Send Mail To Webmaster
        $email = $_POST['email'] ;
        $subject = 'The subject';
        $message =  $email . ' The message .';
        mail("$recipient", $subject, $message, "From:" . $recipient);
    }
?>
```

Obviously you have to get send variables via ajax or send them directly using the form's post method.

Comment: this would be simple as adding a form action="mailto:johndoe@example.com" and method="post" right?

Comment: just the 'method="post"', because the mailto opens a new mailing window. for example, let's say I named the php file "mail.php", in the form declaration: 'method=post action= mail.php'